# JSP not importing second class

Tags: java, hibernate, jsp

This should be a very easy question but I am not able to get this fixed. I have 2 import statements and in Netbeans it does not show any error but when I run the project, I am getting a ClassnotFoundDef error

```
<%@ page import="mastertables.BranchMaster, mastertables.CreateBranchMaster"%>
```

both the classes are in the same package. The error is

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:org/hibernate/HibernateException
```

Please help, I am stuck on this small thing.

Thanks,
Abhijeet.

Comment: Add all the JARs you need, including Hibernate, into the WEB-INF/lib directory of your web application.  Then restart the server.

Answer (score 0):

The application server is not able to retrieve the `org.hibernate.HibernateException` in the classpath. In this case i think you actually have the hibernate jars in your classpath, but the application server is complaining about not being able to find its definition.

Think about it: the most obvious exception for a missing dependency would be a `ClassNotFoundExeption`.
You are not getting this one, and you are also getting problems on instantiating an hibernate exception. Who would throw an hibernate exception if not the hibernate library itself.

So some part of hibernate is already loaded in the classpath, but not this specific class.
In my experience i'd check for libraries version conflicts/mismatch. Check the version of all the hibernate jars and dependencies.